# Unable to use @Serialize with requestfactory

Tags: java, google-app-engine, requestfactory, objectify

I've created an entity with a pojo (ProductVariations) using the label @Serialize to be persisted in GAE through objectify:

```
@Entity
public class Product extends DatastoreObject{

    //Reference without the colors and size information
    @Index private String ref;
    private double price;
    private String details;
    private String description;
    @Serialize private ProductVariations pVariations;
    private List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();

//Getters & Setters
}
```

The problem is that I don't see how to access my pojo with requestfactory because ProductVariations is not a domain type.

In any other case I would use an embeded object but in this particular case I have a nested collection inside ProductVariations witch is a collection in itself (ProductVariations extends ArrayList).

Any suggestions in how to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Why dont you create Proxy interfaces?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question, but you need to implement Serializable in Product if you want to send it over RPC.

Beyond that, are you having problems storing ProductVariations? It's an interesting concept. If it isn't working:

Can you keep ProductVariations in its own @Entity?

Then keep a Key in Product class (or a Long that can you can create a Key from).

For convenience you can also leave ProductVariations in Product but mark it with @Transient and then populate it from the Key/Long in the factory that does your ofy.get().

Comment: Hi. I don't use RPC in server communication I use RequestFactory and that’s the problem. RequestFactory only accepts primitive types or Entity/Value proxies. I implemented serialize in ProductVariations to save it with GAE but I'm unable to access it from client (RequestFactory limitations). I could try to make ProductVariations an @Entity but I think thats not possible because GAE doesn't accept an nested collection inside a collection witch is the case. I could turn the problem around but I’m very interested in a solution to the problem since my solution doesn't seem elegant or practical.

Comment: Fair enough on the RPC comment. I personally haven't found a problem space where RequestFactory is worth the extra hassles beyond RPC. To your question though, can you clarify "GAE doesn't accept an nested collection inside a collection witch is the case."